# Issue on Laravel 8 Migrations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've just started to use Laravel 8, and trying to use Sanctum for API Authentication. Trying first to do the default migrations that the documentation said to do, but I'm getting the following error:

```
QLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -607 unsuccessful metadata update Table users already exists  (SQL: CREATE TABLE "users" ("id" BIGINT NOT NULL, "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "email" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "email_verified_at" TIMESTAMP, "password" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "remember_token" VARCHAR(100), "created_at" TIMESTAMP, "updated_at" TIMESTAMP))
```

But my database is completely EMPTY, not even a table there. Using migrate:refresh returns the same error, using `php artisan migrate:fresh` returns:

```
This database driver does not support dropping all tables.
```

PHP 7.3 and MySQL 8.0.18 - MySQL Community Server are running by AMPPS, on a Windows Server 2019.

Comment: mention your os and database type and version in question.

Comment: how do you know there is no table, did you use software like phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yes. But the problem got solved by on the up() function in each migration, using Schema::connection('mysql')->create(...)...

Comment: This happen when you use multiple database. Check your config/database.php for default database connection name. by default it should be 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

Comment: The issue was that MySQL was already set as default one, idk why changing it solved, but it did

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231322/discussion-between-bapi-and-richard-lucas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue by editing each migration code, on the `up()` function, changing:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table)
```

for

```
Schema::connection('mysql')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with `php artisan migrate:reset`