# Why do I get error on laravel migrate:install?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to use the `php artisan migrate:install` command, but all I receive in return is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -607 unsuccessful metadata update Table migrations already exists  (SQL: CREATE TABLE "migrations" ("id" INTEGER NOT NULL, "migration" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "batch" INTEGER NOT NULL))
```

And I'm pretty sure the table actually don't exist on the database, as the database is completely empty and clean.

I'm using PHP 7.3 and MySQL 8.0.18 - Community Edition, all running by AMPPS on Windows Server 2019. I'm using Laravel 8

Comment: Please share more details, like your debugging attempts

Comment: Double check that the database driver in your `.env` is the same that you're manually checking.

Comment: let discuss on [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231322/discussion-between-bapi-and-richard-lucas)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, @Bapi, as myself made the other question and solved it. But this one is has not been solved the same way, sadly

Comment: @NicoHaase All the info I have is the one I passed on the question, that is what I receive from the terminal when I tried the above. I'm a begineer on Laravel and idk what can be done to overpass that issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue on Laravel 8 Migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67162234/issue-on-laravel-8-migrations)

Comment: @Bapi No, it does not. The question you pointed was made by myself :/

Comment: check if there is mongoDB installed or not. MongoDB might cause such problem.

Comment: @Bapi please share more details. Why should MongoDB throw MySQL errors?

Comment: @Bapi There's not MongoDB installed on the PC.

Comment: To clear the question You should provide your .env, Otherwise it's difficult to answer.

Comment: `php artisan migrate:fresh`?

Comment: Sadly, fresh returns the same error. I kinda gave up of trying using MySQL on this project, and I'm using SQLite for this application now, as it work without issues